# Robolectric : findViewById gives view, but performClick() returns false

Tags: android, testing, robolectric, findviewbyid

I'm using Robolectric to perform unit test on an android app. 
The problem is simple : i can get my Button using findViewById, but calling on it either `performClick()`method or `Robolectric.clickOn()` will return false.

However the button works perfectly, tested through the app or with Robotium unit tests...

here is the test code that doesn't pass :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)    
public class RegisterActivityTest {

private MainActivity mainActivity;
private LoginActivity loginActivity;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    mainActivity=new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.onCreate(null);
    mainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

@Test
public void testButton() throws Exception {
    Button buttonPayment=(Button)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_payment);
    assertNotNull(buttonPayment); // will pass test ( ---> the view is a button and exists ) 
    assertTrue(buttonPayment.performClick()); // raise AssertionError
    assertTrue(Robolectric.clickOn(buttonPayment)); // raise AssertionError as well
  }
}
```

Thanks everybody.

Paul

Comment: I'm curious why you call onCreate and then setContentView(R.layout.main)? Shouldn't your onCreate be calling that?

Comment: you're absolutely right this call is useless. just that I had couple of bugs so did different tries to fix the performClick() problem. I removed it now

Comment: Ok Matt Wolfe the problem was coming from the double call apparently, cause the now asserts pass. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem.. I wrote it up as an answer to help others!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29), the method will return true if you assigned an OnClickListener to the button.

...Did you?

Comment: Yes, since the click passes in the app ( i also double check the code, and indeed I did a button.setOnClickListener() ) Thanks for you help though !

Comment: Can you post your `onCreate()`, or wherever you `setOnClickListener()`? Comment back when you have.

Comment: it's useless i do so now that the problem is solved. it was a simple intent to start a new activity ... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would call `setContentView` within your `onCreate` method. Thus, the call to `setContentView` in your `setUp` method is redundant and may be causing issues.